# Interfaz para ventana "guardar como" archivos en qt-Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

¿Alguno conoce la manera de que, dado un botón en QT, que yo le asigne para guardar algo y, al presionarlo se me desplegue una ventana de ***guardar como***?

Es decir, esa ventana que se abre cuando descargamos algo y nos pide donde lo queremos guardar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar la función: `QString QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & caption = QString(), const QString & dir = QString(), const QString & filter = QString(), QString * selectedFilter = 0, Options options = 0)`

En el slot que recibe la señal de `clicked()`, en mi caso `void on_pushButton_clicked()` ejecutarias esa función.

Por ejemplo en mi caso lo añado a un QLineEdit:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save file");
    ui->lineEdit->setText(filename);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @JuanSebastian Si mi respuesta te ayudo, marcalá como correcta

Comment: vale ya , una pregunta tu funcion getSaveFileName(this, "Save file") que proceso hace internamente?

Comment: @JuanSebastian no entiendo tu pregunta, a qué te refieres exactamente?

Comment: es que veo que llama a una clase y al get que esta dentro de ella , pero esos parametros que recibe el get  , que hace el get con ellos una vez los recibe

Comment: @JuanSebastian la función retorna el nombre del archivo que quieres guardar, recibe parametros para personalizar la ventana

Comment: @JuanSebastian para más información podrias leer su documentación en http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName

Comment: Ya comprendo perfectamente gracias por tu aporte